# How NOT to display records that are in both tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables,

**A1**:

```
ID NAME SIGNUP
1  John 14.04.2011
2  Mike 14.04.2011
3  Gabe 14.04.2011
4  Jane 15.04.2011
```

and **B1**:

```
ID SIGNUP
1  14.04.2011
4  15.04.2011
```

How can I fetch only those records which are in the left table (A) but NOT in the right one (B) based on ID and SIGNUP? The result I'm looking for is this:

```
ID NAME
2  Mike
3  Gabe
```

This is the query I came up with but it's not giving the desired result:

```
SELECT A1.ID, A1.NAME
FROM A1 
LEFT JOIN B1 ON A1.SIGNUP=B1.SIGNUP
AND A1.ID<>B1.ID 
WHERE A1.SIGNUP=TO_DATE('14.04.2011','DD.MM.YYYY')
```

Comment: [A visual explanation of of SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html). This says the same as Michael Krelin's answer, essentially. But with pictures.

Comment: if there is a record with another day in `B1` (say, `1 - 15.04.2011`, do you want it to be omitted?

Comment: @Quassnoi: the tables are populated in such a way that ID and SIGNUP are the same in both tables - B1 is actually a subset of A1. So 1 - 15.04.2011 would not possible (but 4 - 15.04.2011 would be). It was really a simplified version of what I'm working with. Alex Poole's link was also helpful, thanks! I've updated the example tables with ID 4

Comment: I got the desired results using: `SELECT A1.ID, A1.NAME
FROM A1 
LEFT JOIN B1 ON A1.ID=B1.ID
WHERE A1.SIGNUP=TO_DATE('14.04.2011','DD.MM.YYYY') AND B1.ID is null`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*
 FROM a LEFT JOIN b USING (signup) 
 WHERE b.id IS NULL AND *signup thingie*;
```

though this is the way to select rows that have no match I do not see how you want to get the desired result from these tables, I believe you missed something in your illustration.

Comment: This will return all three records from `A`.

Comment: Quassnoi, I believe it will return none. But hence the comment, probably bad *illustration*, so I answered *question*.

Comment: Sorry if the question was vague. I've updated the table examples. If ID and SIGNUP match in both tables then the record should not be displayed

Comment: if you want both to match (or don't want to be precise), just put both into `USING`. I'm not sure if you got where you wanted to by now.

Answer (score 3):

MINUS saves the day:

```
SELECT A1.ID, A1.NAME
FROM A1 
MINUS
SELECT A1.ID, A1.NAME
FROM A1 
JOIN B1 ON A1.SIGNUP=B1.SIGNUP
```

Comment: It may save the day, but I'd expect it to waste performance, unless query planner is way smarter than developer.

Comment: @Michael: way smarter than which developer?

Comment: Quassnoi, I don't want to offend anyone ;-)

Comment: @Michael I chose to use MINUS because it is portable. The downside is that the use of MINUS causes Oracle to sort the sets, so it is indeed slower. I don't think the Oracle tag was there when I wrote my answer. So +1 to your solution as it is a better solution given the database is Oracle.

Comment: Hmm... What do you call "portable"? In this wording, I believe, it won't work on any sql I know well. The tag was there, I know because I assumed MINUS is oracle syntax ;-)

Comment: You are right. The SQL standard is EXCEPT, not MINUS. My bad.

Comment: Who cares about standards, but what sql did you have in mind? Just curious?

Comment: If I use any non-standard extensions they are Oracle ones, cause that's the DBMS I use most.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using:

```
SELECT A1.ID, A1.NAME
FROM A1 
WHERE A1.ID not in (SELECT B1.ID FROM B1)
AND A1.SIGNUP=TO_DATE('14.04.2011','DD.MM.YYYY')
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but it looks like OP is looking for rows with no matching signup, not ids.

Answer (score 1):

If the signups for corresponding IDs in A1 and B1 are always the same, then it's simply:

```
select a1.id,a1.name,
from a1
left join b1
on b1.id=a1.id
where b1.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a1.*
FROM    a1
WHERE   (id, signup) NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  id, signup
        FROM    b1
        )
        AND signup = TO_DATE('14.04.2011', 'DD.MM.YYY')
```